# How to add permission to write to /var/www for my FTP client

Tags: server, permissions, vsftpd

I'm trying to install Tapatalk plugin on my phpbb3 forum

[image]

Write method for automod is FTP and connection is successful. I think the FTP client might not have write permission to /var/www. How can I fix that? I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04 with vsftpd.

> drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 19 02:07 www

Thanks!

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to directly edit files in /var/www/. Better: make a separate upload for ftp and use a cron script to copy files over so you can automate a backup procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the ownership of /var/www to be the same owner that your FTP client uses.

For example if your FTP client runs as 'nobody' then use this command:

```
sudo chown nobody:nobody /var/www
```

Be aware that this will allow your FTP client to do anything to any of the files in /var/www and subdirectories. This might be a security risk. After the install is completed, you could always switch the ownership back to the root user again with:

```
sudo chown root:root /var/www
```

Comment: Thanks, you probably gave me the perfect answer to my question but I'm getting the same error so it might be something else.

Comment: I'm a beginner with the command line, when you say the FTP client runs as 'nobody', what do you mean? How does FTP interface with users in Ubuntu? How do you find out what user the FTP client uses? Do you mean the FTP login credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Changing ownership of /var/www from apache to nobody, is not a good idea ;)
Maybe try instead `usermod -d /var/www -m ftpuser` and go from there?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear as to where you got the information that ownership of /var/www was changed  from apache to nobody. Could you [edit] this answer to rectify that? Thank you.